# How to show MVC logged in username with AngularJs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC 5 / WebApi 2 and AngularJs. I want to display the Logged in username in my view. I know how to display that information using razor but how can I do it with Angular? So basically I need to do this with Angular.

```
<span >Logged In As: @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage", @style = "color:white;float:right" })</span>
```

apiUserController

```
 public class apiUserController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public List<ApplicationUser> Get()
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            List<ApplicationUser> users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            users = context.ApplicationUsers
                .ToList();
            return users;
        }

    }
}
```

Updated

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {

        using (var context = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {

            var user = context.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var loggedInUser = user.UserName;
            return Ok(loggedInUser);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll need to create a service that returns your user information

```
angular.module('app').factory('Authentication', function ($resource) {
    var resource = $resource('/user', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            cache: true
        }
    });
    return resource.get().$promise;
});
```

* note that you'll need to create and endpoint that will send you the user data as json using web api

once you got it done you'll be able to use it in any controller (let's assume you have a homecontroller, it could be a headercontroller or any other)

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', function ($scope, Authentication) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
}]);
```

then use it in your view like:

```
<span >Logged In As: {{authentication.user.username}} </span>
```

**EDIT:**

your api controller as you suggested could be like

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var userId = getCurrentUserId(); //something like that
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
            user = context.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id==userId);
            return user;
        }

    }
```

try to read http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

for routing try to read this article (I guess you are using web api 2)

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: so when you say endpoint you are referring to the api controller? It would need to reach the application user properties? See updated Post please

Comment: yes i'm refering to the api controller, I looked at your example, but you should return the single logged user instead of a list.

Comment: getCurrentUserId is a fake function you'll need to get the logged userId in a some way, that's specific  to your logic and code

Comment: ok, so I believe I got the apicontroller close? no errors, but there is also nothign showing up with breakpoints.

Comment: You should return a json result

Comment: Im kind of confused on this one. can you show me? thanks

Comment: k, what about the route. how do i set the route to the AspNetUser table?

Comment: Id don't understand what you mean when you say "set the route to the table", do you mean the route for your endpoint? like api/user?

Comment: well try to read the article I posted on the answer i guess with that we have covered all the elements you need in case you have another question, close this question an open another, cheers! good luck

Comment: I removed the image you posted in case of any 'security concern'

Comment: why you cache it? he may logout and relog with something else, or stay logged out

Comment: @deadManN I just wanted to fetch the information of the user once, the caching is in the client not in the server, if someone is logged in and hit the login URL the system redirects to the dashboard

Comment: what if i'm in the page once the user logs in? how can i handle it? I really lack knowledge when in comes to AAA, or any other security matters, how they hand shack, how they set cookie or session... and i don't get it when i look at it.

Comment: @deadManN  setup authentication at the API level, by that time I was using servicestack 3.x but the concept could be applied to any API express, sails, feathers are using a similar concept. for more information take a look to https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cheat a little, you can do this in `<head>` in your _Layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(myApp) {
        myApp.username = "@User.Identity.GetUserName()";
        //optional
        myApp.otherStuff = "@moreMvcStuff";
    })(window.myApp = window.myApp || {});
</script>
```

Then start your angular app like this:

```
(function (myApp) {
    "use strict";

    //var app = set up your angular app

    app.run(["$rootScope",
        function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.appSettings = {
                username: myApp.username
            };
        }
    ]);     

})(window.myApp = window.myApp || {});
```

What you are doing is creating a single value on the window called myApp (or name it whatever you like) and passing it into your IIFE. This gives you access to it inside your angular script, bot only in that on block. So if you want it to stick around, you need to put it in a service or your rootScope.

In the app.run block, you can stick it in your rootScope or wherever you want it.

Now in your views you can display it with `{{appSettings.username}}`.

I call this "cheating" because it's specifically for MVC or webforms and it's not the "angular way". If you ever migrated to a fully agnostic html/js client (no asp.net mvc) and web APIs, you'd need to do what is in the currently-accepted answer.