# Pass Signed In user name to AngularJS controller using model binding

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass the signed in user name in the application to an angular controller. I am already passing other parameters using model-binding like this and works perfectly

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="argOne" name="argOne" ng-model="viewModel.test.argumentOne" />
```

I tried passing the user name using a hidden input but I get an undefined value on the controller

```
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="argTwo" name="argTwo" ng-model="viewModel.test.argumentTwo" value=@UserManager.GetUserName(User) />
```

I've seen similar examples here, but nothing specific when getting a value directly from the UserManager class from ASP.NET core

Update: I am not asking how to display the Signed in user, the question is how can I pass that value to the angular controller using model binding like shown in the first line of code on the question, but with a hidden field or something similar that the user can't see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show MVC logged in username with AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239071/how-to-show-mvc-logged-in-username-with-angularjs)

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci That question is for showing the logged in user on the webpage. I am asking how to send that value to my angular controller

Comment: Why don't you keep it in a scope variable? What's the point to put it in a hidden field once you're using AngularJS framework?

Comment: I believe the username is getting filled by the server?

Comment: @MuliYulzary yes, the userName is in memory at that point. I am using the default ApplicationUser from IdentotyUser

Comment: @akazemis I am new to Angular and don't have the big picture yet. The viewModel object is the "controller" object (postsController as viewModel). I simply need to set the userName property of that object. I will read about the scope variable to see if it helps me

Comment: @akazemis I did my reading about the scope variable. Is it a good practice to keep the scope variable instead of an alias? (viewModel) in my case.

Comment: @Banana Yes I think so. In this case I believe scope variable works better. As you can set it in your application scope only once, and use it everywhere (in the all controllers). I'm going to post an answer to give a hint

Comment: @Banana But my assumption is that you're not going to use it to identify your user on the server-side and it's just for display purposes. Otherwise you need to consider security threats such as user identify forgery.

Comment: @akazemis I am on the early stage of a web application. What I am actually trying to to is what you said, use the userName to identify what user is making the requests to the API. I want to focus now on functionality and am planning to leave security and a better user identification for later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you want to do, I'd suggest you to use scope variables to keep the username rather than keeping it in a hidden field. As what you want to keep is a username I'm assuming that you may need to use it in various controller throughout your angularjs app. So I'd rather keep it in application scope to take advantage of scope inheritance.

So What I'm suggesting looks like this :

In the HTML, you assign the username to the pertinent scope variable `$rootScope.username` :

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-init="$rootScope.username='@UserManager.GetUserName(User)'">
 ....
<div ng-controller="myController">
    Your Username is : {{$rootScope.username}}
</div>
```

I the JS you can use it everywhere:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function(){ 
// you can use $scope.username in this code and it would be inherited from the $rootScope.username
...
});
```

Comment: It worked beautifully. I used ng-init to set the value of the userName, didn't know I could do it that way. I didn't set the $rootScope value, but I will keep in mind your recommendation if I see the need further in the project. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code to this

```
var user = UserManager.GetUserName(User)
if(user)
{
 $scope.userName = user; 
}

<input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="argTwo" name="argTwo" ng-model="userName" />
```